# Rewiring a display case fixture light

Tags: light-fixture

I'm rewiring a display case at my store. The existing wiring has 4 wires including a yellow one attached to the red wire. Theres a Green, White, Red & the yellow wire coming from the fixture itself. I'd like to replace that with a 3 wire 14ga cord. Whats the yellow wire & which of the 3 wires do I attach it?

Comment: Florescent light?  Pictures of existing would help.

Comment: What type of fixture and voltage is this? I would guess the red yellow are the hots , the white neutral and the green ground. If this is the case. Red yellow to the black on the cord. White to white and green to green.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be within the scope of "home" improvement, but I'm not sure where the community stands on commercial electrical questions. Some places may require commercial electrical work to be performed by a licensed Electrician.